# Automatically set Excel number of cell rows between Two of the same variables?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I've been given the task of cleaning up a bunch of excel data that is organized in the messiest of ways. I'm looking at a bunch of real estate listings, but instead of organizing everything by columns, the data provider organized everything in rows. For example:

```
Listing 1:

ROOM FOR RENT

blank row

LOCATION

blank row

DATE 

blank row

ADDRESS 

blank row

DESCRIPTION

blank row

CONTACT

blank row

blank row

blank row

Listing 2:

ROOM FOR RENT

and so on.
```

Now, converting the data into columns is no problem because most of the data structure is fit, and therefore there is a fixed number of cell rows between each variable (see the blank spaces). I just use the offset function, and every 14 or so rows I know is the Listing description, every 16 rows is the location, every 18 rows is contact, etc etc.

However, every now and then the data will have either an extra blank space or one less blank space between the listings and it completely screws up the offset (since all data after the hitch will then be one row ahead or behind). My question is: if I have two rows that are exactly the same (for example, ROOM FOR RENT), is there a way I can fix the number of cell rows between all instances of those rows and have excel add or subtract blank rows accordingly to whatever rule i set ? this would help me a ton.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Native Excel has no method to do that. You can easily do that with VBA.  But a complete solution using VBA or PowerQuery might be a better approach.

Comment: Hi, This may seem like a crazy idea, but since this file has a quasi-pattern why not run it through some text-editor to remove blank rows, whitespaces etc, input some tabs or commas, export to csv, import to excel and at the end enjoy a neat file?

Comment: As a quick way to remove your blank-spaces, you can start with a `TEXTJOIN()` and use whatever as a delimiter (use something that doesn't appear in any of the data). Make sure you set `ignore_empty` to `TRUE`. So now you have a cell with all your data, separated by your delimiter. Use `Text to Columns` to convert that cell (containing your list) into a column of data (how to use [text to columns][1])




  [1]: https://www.adinstruments.com/support/knowledge-base/how-can-comma-separated-list-be-converted-cells-column-lt

Comment: In your real data, how do you know which is which, when there are extra lines between each?  Is there a separate Key that has the order of valid entries?  Or is there a lable.  If there is a Key, and if all entries are always present, just remove all the blank lines. If there are labels, you can perhaps use those.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I manually counted the numbers between the cells haha. I think I may have to learn to just use vba or something.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use the options native Excel gives you!

1. Select the column that includes all the info
   2.a in the main Ribbon -> Home -> Editing(all the way to the right) -> find & select -> GoTo Special [image]
   2.b in the menu select "Blanks", now all the blank cells in column A have been selected.
   [image]
2. main Ribbon -> Home -> Cells(just to the left of editing) -> Delete -> Delete Sheet Rows

Now you have only consecutive cells with filled data! this can be done too with vba that should look like this
press Alt+F11 to open the vba editor,
left click in the project window -> insert -> module

copy and paste the following code which should work just fine!

```
Sub Delete_empty_rows ()

Dim c as long

For Every C in Range("A:A")
      If c = "" Then Rows(ActiveCell.Row).EntireRow.Delete
  End if
Next c

End Sub
```

Please let me know if you run into any problems!